# Can I get Neo4J query results back as a graph?

Tags: c#, neo4j

I am working on a proof of concept for my organization using Neo4j. As an example, I've chosen to model a companies management hierarchy (who manages who, who is managed by X etc). It seems like it would work well in a graph, but I can't find any way to get the data back out of Neo4j in the way I would want to display it.

The query  I need is: **Tell me everyone that reports to person X, all the way down.** So that means, everyone who directly reports to X and anyone who reports to them etc.

I see I can do that in Cypher, but it returns a flattened 2d result. But that isn't very helpful since it doesn't describe the management structure of the results.

It seems what I really want is a graph of the people all the way down. Can this be done without doing queries for every level of management?

I am using the C# Neo4JClient, but I am interested in any solution at this point.

Comment: How does your cypher statement look so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return all paths to the root `X` of your structure.

```
start x=node:people(name='foo')
match path = x<-[:REPORTS_TO*]-person
return path
```

You can also return `nodes(path)` or `rels(path)` or use any of the expressions `filter`, `length`, `extract` or the predicates `ALL`, `ANY`, `SINGLE`, `NONE` on the path collection.

Comment: Yes, that works but it is still a table of results. It means parsing and reconstituting a graph on the client end. What I want is to just get a graph from neo4j. It seems like a letdown to express all of this data nicely in a graph but only get the results back in tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for extracting trees:

Note: This solution works at my project but I had to change it for your question since we have some other unnecessary constraints.

After finding all root entities for extracting,

```
With entity as rootEntity
```

I've added these matches to the query:

```
match
    rootEntity-[*0..]->subEntity, 
    parentEntity-->subEntity
```

and this where:

```
where rootEntity = subEntity or (rootEntity-[*0..]->parentEntity)
```

then, I returned (distinct) the data as follows :

```
id(rootEntity), 
id(parentEntity),
id(entity),
subEntity
```

the rest of the solution is C#:

First some data fix is needed because NEO4J will return the root entities several times (one for each incoming relationships):

```
results.ForEach(
        x =>
        {
            if (x.Id == x.RootId)
                x.ParentId = 0;
        });
```

and distinct by Id:

```
results =
    results
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();
```

Then, we can build the tree:

```
    ....
    var trees = results
        .GroupBy(x => x.RootId)
        .Select(singleTreeEntities => GenerateSingleEntity(singleTreeEntities.Key, singleTreeEntities))

    return trees;
}

private Entity GenerateSingleEntity(long id, IEnumerable<Entities> treeEntities)
{
    var currEntity = treeEntities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    return new Entity
    {
        Id = id,
        SomeData = currEntity.SubEntity.SomeData,
        SomeOtherData = currEntity.SubEntity.SomeOtherData,
        ChildEntities =
            treeEntities
                .Where(x => x.ParentId == id)
                .Select(x => GenerateSingleEntity(x.Id, treeEntities)))
    };
}
```